CommunityToolkit/Maui stopped compiling after VS update
Maybe someone has encountered this.
I updated VS to version 17.12.3
at the same time switched from windows 10 to 11
and after that my solution stopped assembling
github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui
various errors pop up
Having tried many different ways to solve these errors, I decided to return to win10. But naturally it did not help (the latest errors (CS0016, CS0006))
and I would like to put this issue aside and move on. Moreover, it is not at all critical for me. But I already have a sporting interest. Since a lot of time was spent.
Maybe someone's solution assembles?

Most probably related to this: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/23097
